# Android Studio 3.2 canary build is not rendering Navigation tag

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Android studio 3.2 canary 14 is not rendering the navigation tag. It just shows the waiting for a build to finish.

navigation_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_nav_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />
</navigation>
```

[image]

Comment: same experience. have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- turn on experimental feature "enable navigation editor"

  under `menu> android studio>preferences>experimental`
- clean and rebuild project
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's working on the [latest](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) versions 3.2 canary 16.